# imshow window is not responding after I put my codes - for the connection of python and arduino- inside its loop, why is that?

Tags: opencv, barcode-scanner, arduino-uno, face-recognition, python-3.9

This project is face-recognition with barcode. It needs to detect the face first before it can scan the barcodes. The flow is fine not unless after it detect someone face the window in imshow is not responding anymore, the webcam got froze. I want the webcam to continue moving while processing my codes, how can I do that?

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
      raise IOError("Cannot open webcam") \

temp = ""
while True:

    success, eImgs = cap.read()
    if success:
         font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
         datet = str(datetime.now())
         frame = cv2.putText(eImgs, datet, (10, 50), font, 1, (0, 0, 128), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
         # eImgs_v1 = cv2.resize (eImgs, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0,25)
         eImgs_v1 = cv2.cvtColor(eImgs, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

         facesWebcam = face_recognition.face_locations(eImgs_v1)
         encodesWebcam = face_recognition.face_encodings(eImgs_v1, facesWebcam)

        for encodeKnown_v2, faceLoc in zip(encodesWebcam, facesWebcam):
            facesCompared = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeKnown, encodeKnown_v2)
            faceDistance = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeKnown, encodeKnown_v2)
            faceIndex = np.argmin(faceDistance)

            if facesCompared[faceIndex]:
                 employeeName = ListNames[faceIndex]
                 y = employeeName
                 if temp == "" or temp != name:
                      print(name)
                      temp = name

                      if y:
                          print(y)
                          print("AUTHORIZED")

                          time.sleep(1)

                          **# Arduino and Python connection**
                          *arduino = serial.Serial('COM9', 115200, timeout=.1)
                          time.sleep(1)
                          print("The system is ready!")
                          while True:
                               barcode = arduino.readline()[:-2]
                               strbarcode = barcode.decode('utf-8')
                               if strbarcode:
                                     x = strbarcode
                                     print(x)
                                     if y == x:
                                         print('Have a nice day!')
                                         time.sleep(3)
                                         print("Next Employee please!")
                                     else:
                                         print('This is not yours!')*


                      else:
                          print("UNAUTHORIZED")

                 p1, p2, p3, p4 = faceLoc
                 cv2.rectangle(eImgs, (p1, p2), (p3, p4), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                 cv2.putText(eImgs, y, (p1, p3), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        

    cv2.imshow('EMPLOYEE', eImgs)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use deepface. Its stream function applies face recognition with several state-of-the-art face recognition models.

```
models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID', 'Dlib', 'ArcFace']

#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.stream(db_path = 'C:/my_db'
   , model_name = models[0]
   , enable_face_analysis = False #to disable age, gender, emotion prediction
)
```